# How to implement periodical requests in Mule ESB?

Tags: mule

I need my Mule application to process periodical requests (for example, my application will send requests to a service every 5 seconds and process responses from this service).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Quartz trigger and transport built into Mule ESB. It does exactly what you want, initializing flows at a given interval or CRON expression.

Very comprehensive documentation can be found [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Quartz+Transport+Reference).

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution would be using `<poll/>` and configuring frequency attribute in it
Reference :-https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Poll+Reference

example:-

```
 <flow name="test1" doc:name="test1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <poll frequency="1000" doc:name="Poll">
     <set-payload value="Polling started at particular interval !!!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>      
    </poll>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
 </flow>
```